# Why function parameter not work in square bracket when i use recursive function

Tags: javascript

I am using recursive function and i call JSON value in function parameter that name is "optionVal" and also call count that show how many time my function call? Now the problem i face that when call count in square bracket browser show error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" then i use number like 0 1 instead count the function work properly. Why this occur can anyone explain.

```
    var defaultAdd = document.getElementById('dropdown-select');
    var optionVal =
        [
            {
                name: "Animals",
                child: [
                    {
                        name: "Dog",
                        child: [
                            {
                                name: "Huskey"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "German Shephard"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Fish",
                        child: [
                            {
                                name: "Whale"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Shark"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Metal",
                child: [
                    {
                        name: "Hard",
                        child: [
                            {
                                name: "Gold"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Iron"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Soft",
                        child: [
                            {
                                name: "Alluminium"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Mercury"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Cloths",
                child: [
                    {
                        name: "Resin",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Cotton",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Linen",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Denim",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Lead",
            }
        ]
    var array = ['<ul>'];

    navbar(optionVal, 0);

    function navbar(optionVal, count) {
        console.log(optionVal[count].name)
        array.push('<li>' + optionVal[count].name + '</li>');

        if (count >= optionVal.length) {
            return false;
        } else {
            navbar(optionVal, count + 1)
        }
    }

    defaultAdd.innerHTML = array.join("");
```

Comment: Because `[]` is an array

Comment: yeah, But when i console 'optionVal[count].name' they show proper 5 value but i dont know why this same not work  in array.push line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake was, you are exceeding the limits of the array (line 87 "f (count >= optionVal.length - 1)". See the code bellow:

```js
var defaultAdd = document.getElementById('dropdown-select');
var optionVal =
    [
        {
            name: "Animals",
            child: [
                {
                    name: "Dog",
                    child: [
                        {
                            name: "Huskey"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "German Shephard"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Fish",
                    child: [
                        {
                            name: "Whale"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Shark"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Metal",
            child: [
                {
                    name: "Hard",
                    child: [
                        {
                            name: "Gold"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Iron"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Soft",
                    child: [
                        {
                            name: "Alluminium"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Mercury"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Cloths",
            child: [
                {
                    name: "Resin",
                },
                {
                    name: "Cotton",
                },
                {
                    name: "Linen",
                },
                {
                    name: "Denim",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Lead",
        }
    ]
var array = ['<ul>'];

navbar(optionVal, 0);

function navbar(optionVal, count) {
    console.log(optionVal[count].name)
    array.push('<li>' + optionVal[count].name + '</li>');

    if (count >= optionVal.length - 1) { // Your error was here! :)
        return false;
    } else {
        navbar(optionVal, count + 1)
    }

// You can refactor for better readability
// if (count < optionVal.length - 1) { // Max index 4 - 1 = 3
//     navbar(optionVal, count + 1)
// } else {
//     return false;
// }

}

defaultAdd.innerHTML = array.join("");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {background: white}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="dropdown-select">
        
    </ul>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't understand how the code run by applying its -1

Comment: The length of your array is 4. The index count goes from 0 to 3 (0,1,2,3) the index 4 doesn´t exist, that recursive call is trying to go from 0 to 4, which doesn't exist.